# Error in Simply Scheme Program

Tags: scheme, racket

I am using a program from the Simply Scheme book:

```
(require (planet dyoo/simply-scheme))
(define (combinations size set)
  (cond ((= size 0) '(()))
    ((empty? set) '())
    (else (append (prepend-every (first set)
                                 (combinations (- size 1)
                                               (butfirst set)))
                  (combinations size (butfirst set))))))
```

But, when I run it I get this error:

```
 expand: unbound identifier in module in: prepend-every
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

I am using DrRacket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that is that "prepend-every" isn't defined anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

That function is defined earlier in the chapter, assuming you're reading Chapter 1.  See [prepend-every](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch1/showing#g20).  [Chapter 1](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch1/showing.html) assumes you're doing the entire chapter in a single sitting, so some demo programs there will depend on functions that the authors had just talked about a few paragraphs before.